# Typescript: Why destructuring an object doesn't hold type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the following, I would expect this to fail as I've stated `afternoon` should be of type `number`, but it doesn't fail.

My guess is I'm destructuring incorrectly as hovering over the word `afternoon` when it returns shows the type as `any` (in VS Code).

Alternatively, it could all be wrong, this is literally my first play with Typescript, not getting it, yet!

```js
const greetings =  {
    morning: "Good morning.",
    evening: "Good evening.",
    afternoon: "Good afternoon.",
};

interface AboutGreetingTypes {
    morning: string,
    evening: string,
    afternoon: number,
};

const aboutGreeting = ({copy}): AboutGreetingTypes => {
    const d = new Date();
    const timeInHours = d.getHours();

    const { morning, evening, afternoon } = copy;

    if (timeInHours < 12) {
        return morning;
    }
    if (timeInHours > 18) {
        return evening;
    }
    if (timeInHours > 12) {
        return afternoon;
    }
};

console.log(aboutGreeting({copy: greetings}));
```

Comment: It looks like afternoon has the wrong type?
`afternoon: "Good afternoon.",` vs: `afternoon: number,` in the interface does not match. I don't get how `copy` got into the mix.

Comment: You'll want to spend some dedicated time reading through the TypeScript handbook. Here's a link to [getting started for JS programmers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const aboutGreeting = ({copy}): AboutGreetingTypes => {
```

This line declares a function that accepts a single untyped object and returns an `AboutGreetingTypes`. Since the argument has no declared type, it is assumed to be `any`, which lets you do anything without without a type error.

---

What I think you want is a function that accepts an object that has a `copy` property that has value of an `AboutGreetingTypes`.

That would look like this:

```
const aboutGreeting = ({ copy }: { copy: AboutGreetingTypes }) => {
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gJwKZKgSzHCMC8MYDeAsAFD74C2ICYGcAXDAEQDiIIAJjFTXQHRMANKXIwkANyS1MjVuy4Sp-ISPIBDAGZQkNdmFltOMTdt3gBwkgF8A3KVIZTGtcCQwAggCMQAVygtkVDoAFQBPAAckbGIych5pBhhoBDpLUUUExmTU1XwTHTA9RjAfCk8dS1t7ElBIWDVvPwCUdExcGAAKAhhQcNCYK0Zu3tDGL19-QNa4MMjsKwBKXAA+Qlye8GgYLjwwJAB3GAARNW0OhbtY-Fqt9AokAEkwAAlfBGw8Dj44VFefd-Ol3WN1g3XiqTEkgSgmMWgKegG7RGlwA9CjRBjMVjsTjRAA9AD81VEaA0nTujxeb2wAB4YABGABMSxi2OQUH+YG41ASqPRuPwhPWVnWpPJaHuTz+7xgq3pAA4WetROzOZClJg+QLBUSrgNRWSOhSpdTZQzmWs9SrUGr8mYwFrtUK9SLrECapsQAAbJB8L0gOAdBoTZpBTBdEaMRAtOgQRYXIA) which still has some errors, but those resolving those are answers to different questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your function parameter type should be `{copy: AboutGreetingTypes}` not just `AboutGreetingTypes`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.